# Create product alert stock block

Tags: magento-1.7, products, out-of-stock, alert

I'm working on an ajax module and I have to create a product alert button block.
I'm using this code to create the block:

```
$stockAlertBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'productalert/product_view',
            'alert_stock',
            array('template' => 'productalert/product/view.phtml')
        );

        $stockAlertBlock->setHtmlClass('alert-stock link-stock-alert');
        $stockAlertBlock->setSignupLabel('Register to receive stock alert');
```

The block will be created but the link is not working because I'm not able to set correctly the product.

I've tried

```
$stockAlertBlock->setSignupUrl('productalert/add/stock/product_id/' . $simpleProduct->getId().'/uenc/'.Mage::helper('core/url')->getEncodedUrl().'/');
```

but it's not working.

Do you have any suggestion?
thanks

Comment: What is not working? Where is the second code from? NEVER tell someone it is not working, always describe "it" :-)

Comment: is the last parameter I miss to make it works. I guess I'm wrong generating the uenc part.

Answer (score 1):

The product is set here:

```
\Mage_ProductAlert_Block_Product_View::_prepareLayout
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
    if ($product && $product->getId()) {
        $this->_product = $product;
    }

    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

I'm not sure whether `_prepareLayout()` is called if you create the block this way. So you can try to set it in the registry beforehand, the alternative is to either `extend` the block to make `_product` accessable or use reflection.

Comment: I just have to setSignupUrl. I'm using $stockAlertBlock->setSignupUrl('productalert/add/stock/product_id/' . $simpleProduct->getId().'/uenc/'.Mage::helper('core/url')->getEncodedUrl().'/'); But doesn't work. can you help please?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the information, so it is readable?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by a simple way.

Rewrite helper class `Mage_ProductAlert_Helper_Data` of `Mage_ProductAlert` module and create `a custom function` and  on this funtion write code for `custom url for product alert`.

```
<?php
class Amit_CustomProductAlert_Helper_Data extends Mage_ProductAlert_Helper_Data
{
    public function getStockSimpleSaveUrl($type=stock,$product_id)
    {
        return $this->_getUrl('productalert/add/' . $type, array(
            'product_id'    => $product_id,
            Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => $this->getEncodedUrl()
        ));
    }

}

?>
```

Now using the function you can get product stock alert url at any where

```
Mage::helper('productalert')->getStockSimpleSaveUrl('stock',$productId))
```